# move(y,x) in ncurses in GNU C on Linux

Tags: c, ncurses

I have a the following piece of code using ncurses. I would like to know whether I can use a single move function to print a few lines.

For Example:

```
move(25,25);
printw("Line 1\n");
printw("Line 2\n");
```

Line 1 prints at (25,25) location but Line 2 prints at (26,0) if I don't use move(26,25). Can I avoid the second move and still print Line 2 at (26,25)????

Comment: Have you tried to define a new window and then wprintw in this window ?

Comment: I created a new window but how do I maneuver using just one move();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a new window if what you want to print has to be aligned. Shortly :

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main()
{
  WINDOW* mywin;

  initscr();
  cbreak();
  keypad(stdscr, TRUE);


  int height=15;
  int width=30;
  int starty=25;
  int startx=25;

  printw("F9 to exit");
  refresh();

  mywin = newwin(height, width, starty, startx);
  mvwprintw(mywin,0,0,"First line\n");
  wprintw(mywin,"Second line");
  wrefresh(mywin);

  while(getch() != KEY_F(9)) {}

  endwin();
  return 0;
}
```

If this approach does not fit, then you'll have to move manually to next position you want to print.